# Passing context on test cases for React shallow enzyme -jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

How can I pass the context and extract the data in a helper method?

See the below snippet:

```
import AppContext from '../../context/AppContext'
import extractDatta from '../../helper';

class App extends Component{
  static contextType = AppContext

  componentWillMount(){
   const resolvedData = extractData("/home",this.context)
  }

 render(){
   return(
  )
 }

}
```

helper/index.js:

```
const extractData = (path, context) => {
  // getting context as undefined 
}
```

App.test.js:

```
describe('App test suites', () => {
  let wrapper;
  let appContext;
  beforeEach(() => {
    appContext = {name: "Application"}
    wrapper = shallow(<Supplier />, { appContext })
  })
  it('Should render the App Component', () => {
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  })
})
```

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not implemented in Enzyme, yet. Having the same issues here. https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1553. Did you find a workaround?

Answer (score 3):

So here is my hacky workaround whilst the Enzyme team work on finishing [https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1553](React 16 support). I'm providing the legacy `contextTypes` on the component class, allowing the context to be passed as per the docs.

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

describe('App test suites', () => {
  let wrapper;
  let appContext;
  beforeEach(() => {
    appContext = {name: "Application"}

    // Hack in the legacy context API just for tests. You'll get a warning, but it 
    // ought to work...
    Supplier.contextTypes = {
      name: PropTypes.string
    }

    wrapper = shallow(<Supplier />, { appContext })
  })

  it('Should render the App Component', () => {
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

That probably wouldn't help. But shouldn't you pass Options object with context parameter name instead of appContext?

`wrapper = shallow(<Supplier />, { context: appContext })`